# How do you use a click funciton that has a lot of classes in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="card-block">something</div>
<div class="card-block">something</div>
<div class="card-block">something</div>
<div class="card-block">something</div>
<div class="card-block">something</div>
```

So, I have something like this in my code, I was wondering how do add a click function that grabs the specific div that was clicked?

I thought this would work `$('.card-block').on('click', function() { "do something" });`

Ok, so I guess I forgot to mention my DOM is being build dynamically, and it's constantly being built dynamically every time the user clicks on a button, or resizes the window.

Comment: Use the `this` keyword to refer to the element that raised the event

Comment: What you've got should work, unless the dom is being built dynamically

Comment: define: `does not work`

Comment: You missed a closing single quote at `$('.card-block')`

Comment: Yes, my DOM is being build dynamically. How do I fix it? I thought it was funny, cause i thought it should work

Comment: If your DOM is built dynamically you need to use a delegated event handler. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.card-block').on('click', function() { var div = $(this); });
```

You can use this keyword to get clicked div. In case your element is added dynamically, then use this code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.card-block', function() { var div = $(this); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, if it' doesn't it probably means that you're binding the click event when the element isn't there yet.
Try to delegate the event to the body:

```
$('body').on('click', '.card-block', function(e) {
    var your_div = $(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. It will also attach `click` event for `dynamically loaded` elements having class `card-block`.

```
$(document).on('click','.card-block', function() { 
  var x = $(this);//It will be the appropriate div
});
```